# Переконвертировать js в c#

Tags: javascript, c#, конвертер

Здравствуйте! Есть небольшой js-скрипт. Может поможет кто-то в конвертировании его в C#? А то я в js как-то не особо разбираюсь. Сейчас работает через интерпретатор Noesis, но не охота подключать лишнюю библиотеку ради такого небольшого скрипта.
Собственно скрипт:

```
function Resolve(slog, secr)
{
   var cn = 0;
   var s = [];
   function C(i,s,o){ return (s.charCodeAt(i) - o) ^ (cn|1) ^ ((cn++ & 1)?i:0) ^ 0x55 }
   for(var i=0; i<slog.length; i++)
   {
      var x = C(i,secr,33) ^ C(i,slog,0);
      s.push(x);
   }
   return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, s);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delegate int delC(int i, String s, int o);

static String Resolve(String slog, String secr)
{
    int cn = 0;
    char[] res = new char[slog.Length];

    delC C =  (i,s,o) => (s[i] - o) ^ (cn | 1) ^ (((cn++ & 1)==1) ? i : 0) ^ 0x55;
    for(var i=0; i<slog.Length; i++)
    {
        var x = C(i,secr,33) ^ C(i,slog,0);
        res[i] = (char)x;
    }
    return new String(res);
}
```

Comment: Ух ты, как все просто. Спасибо!